# Flattening out a power spectral density

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, power-spectral-density, signal-synthesis

The situation is as follows. I am generating a white noise voltage signal with a certain power spectral density amplitude of choice, from 0 to some cutoff frequency, for example 200 MHz. This proceeds as follows: first I make my white noise in Mathematica. I use a technique in which I convolve unit white noise (with variance = 1) with a self made FIR filter based on the amplitudes I want the real noise to have. This gives me a time trace, which corresponds to the desired spectrum very well after analysing it with periodograms. I then load the time trace into an arbitrary waveform generator (AWG). The AWG then produces the pattern, and I look at it through a spectrum analyzer. This helps me verify if the noise is as desired.

Now, there are a number of difficulties in this of course, but the main one turns out to be the finite sampling rate of the AWG. The one I use produces signals at 1.2GSamples, and thus cannot be expected to produce signals at over 600 MHz (the Nyquist frequency). However, a priori this is not a big deal; my cutoff is at 200 MHz anyway. But in practice, the AWG doesn't just produce perfect noise up to 600 MHz. When producing white noise there is a downward trend in the spectral density for increasing frequencies, which is undesired.

My question, is how I can postprocess my data knowing the downward trend in the spectral density to make it more flat. Of course 100% flatness will never be achieved, but I am sure that one could somehow mitigate the decline in some way, getting it better than what it is right now. I have to my disposal a theoretical spectrum that I want, a digital time domain trace that would produce this spectrum if perfectly executed, and the analyzed spectrum realized by the AWG. Is there some way I can combine this information to achieve my goal?

To clarify what I mean, below is a plot of the measured PSD, overplotted with the PSD that was to be produced. The part after the cutoff is simply the noise floor of the spectrum analyzer, which is not a problem.
[image]

Note that the low frequency point that deviates can be ignored, this is due to the spectrum analyzer.

Comment: One idea that came to my mind is that, essentially, the AWG is applying a filter to my flat spectral density. Would I perhaps be able to construct an inverse of this filter, based on my measurements, and apply this to the time trace? I am not sure how one would proceed with this though.

Comment: One approach is to use the Wiener-Hopf equations to make an equalizer, since you have your original signal and the resulting signal (this will solve for the channel compensator)- see my earlier posts on this, if you have trouble finding I can include a link later (or search for my name on MathWorks code exchange site where I provided the code there as well as an example.

Comment: Also see my response to "how to make CIC compensation filter"  for similar techniques that could possibly be applied to this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have to say I don't immediately see how to apply your sinc function approach to this particular question. I'm not terribly experienced with filters, so that is probably my bad. I'm trying to look into the Wiener Hopf approach that you mentioned now, although I am mostly finding them to be differential equation related, but I'll dig into your post history!

Comment: Perhaps important to note is that I do not have the actual time trace produced by the AWG, just the power spectral density. One source I found on those Wiener Hopf equations gave a way to construct the filter from the time series before and after, but I don't see how that is easily translated to the frequency domain. I suppose that you referred to http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57531-equalize-tx-rx-depth-ntaps- earlier on, which I think (?) takes a time trace at the in and output, does it not?

Comment: Yes you would need the time domain waveforms for the Wiener Hopf equations which you do not have, so focus your attention more on the inverse sinc to the degree that it is a filter that can compensate for "passband droop" like you have.

Comment: So to describe simply, create an FIR filter that has a peaking response as it goes out higher in freq (such as the inverse sinc) and use it to filter your time domain waveform prior to loading into the arb. You can convolve it's coefficients with the filter you have if you want to use one filter. Are you looking for a specific design approach to make the peaking filter?

Comment: I would encourage you to pursue the sinc compensator; the droop you are seeing is very likely due to the DAC reconstruction in the ARB, which would follow a sinc response, so the 3 tap compensator filter should work quite well for you.

Comment: I will look into it for sure. I am finding it a bit technical (in the sense that I am an outsider to the field) so it is taking me some time to grasp how one would implement it, but it might be a more general approach to solving the problem that'll work well. As an aside, would it not be the finite sampling rate? Or is that contained in the DAC reconstruction? I'd interpret that more as a finite resolution.

Comment: It is the fact that the DAC reconstructs the analog waveform by holding the sample value constant until the next sample occurs - this "first order hold" creates the frequency roll-off you are seeing.

Comment: We shouldn't fill up too many comments here- email me at boschen@loglin.com and I may be able to help you later